# Send objects to layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Is it possible to send a TextView or any object to a layaout without any previavente that TextView, that is, create a new item from the layout from java?

How do you do?

Comment: I don't get your idea? What do you want to do? Tell people what you want instead of how you do that.

Comment: I wanted to do exactly what you answered me @dmitri-timofti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add views to a ViewGroup (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc.) programmatically by calling `addView()`. Don't forget to set LayoutParams to the view you're adding.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout =  (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);

TextView text = new TextView(this);
text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

linearLayout.addView(text);
```

Comment: Thank you very very very much, That's exactly what I needed